# How to modify Android for Raspberry Pi, mainly iot_rpi3.img

Tags: android, image, kernel

downloaded the iot_rpi3.img file from [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html). I also compiled a custom kernel for Android Raspberry PI following:

https://github.com/android-rpi/device_brcm_rpi3

I would like to replace the kernel and flash it to the Raspberry Pi. An approach I thought would work is to modify the iot_rpi.img file. So far no luck. Here is what I tried:

I used yaffey v0.2 from google, and it could not identify the file. On Linux, I tried to mount it using ext4 partition with no luck. I did

```
fdisk -l iot_rpi.img
```

and I got:

```
Device           Start     End Sectors  Size Type
iot_rpi3.img1       40  131111  131072   64M unknown
iot_rpi3.img2   131112  133159    2048    1M unknown
iot_rpi3.img3   133160  135207    2048    1M unknown
iot_rpi3.img4   135208  200743   65536   32M unknown
iot_rpi3.img5   200744  266279   65536   32M unknown
iot_rpi3.img6   266280 1314855 1048576  512M unknown
iot_rpi3.img7  1314856 2363431 1048576  512M unknown
iot_rpi3.img8  2363432 2363559     128   64K unknown
iot_rpi3.img9  2363560 2363687     128   64K unknown
iot_rpi3.img10 2363688 2365735    2048    1M unknown
iot_rpi3.img11 2365736 2431271   65536   32M unknown
iot_rpi3.img12 2431272 2496807   65536   32M unknown
iot_rpi3.img13 2496808 3021095  524288  256M unknown
iot_rpi3.img14 3021096 3545383  524288  256M unknown
iot_rpi3.img15 3545384 8912855 5367472  2.6G unknown
```

Any ideas on how to mount this .img file? Using 7-zip, I could extract few of the inner img files, but non of them had the zImage/ vmlinux or similar file.

Any ideas on what may be the easiest way to modify the kernel, or boot.img on the Raspberry Pi if it is not this approach?

Comment: I changed the `boot/cmdline.txt` of my android things image by writing the whole image with etcher (GUI image writer for linux) to an SD card. After the image was written, ubuntu nautilus automatically mounted all partitions of the SD card and I could edit `boot/cmdline.txt`. May be this approach works for your modified kernel too.